# Monero mining compiler error

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to compile monero on ubuntu 16 LTS, but i get the following compilation error (see screenshot), I am running the Linux machine in esxi hypervisor (virtual machine). It seems there is an issue with the assembler?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to build on a i686 Linux platform ?

Comment: yes, giving lscpu shows it is i686, 32 and 64 bit

Comment: Are you sure you are using https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/linux32 ?

Comment: Wait a minute.. are trying to build Monero or Cpuminer-multi ?

Comment: i tried to compile monero but it did not work, then i tried to compile cpuminer multi, which also did not work. Now i managed to get it to work, with ./configure using a parameter i found online.

Comment: Please make your question more clear to reflect that and please add your solution as an answer for others

Answer (score 1):

worked with the following 
 ./configure CFLAGS="*-march=native*" --with-crypto --with-curl